# Help implementing a custom signal source in GNU Radio

Tags: gnuradio

I am trying to implement a custom signal source in GNU Radio, but I am stuck. The idea is to generate a delayed windowed `sinc()` function, i.e. a function having its peak at `t=0`, then at `t=T`, then at `t=2T`, ..., then at `t=nT`, etc.
I thought of a `rect()` function as window, defined as
$$
rect(x)
=
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{ if } \mid x \mid < 1/2\\
0 &\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$
In other words, the idea is to implement a function of the form
$
sinc(t-nT)
rect[ (t-nT/2)/s ]
$,
with $s$ the desired span of the `rect()` function. I also include a possible offset from 0 thanks to the variable `offset`
with a possible offset and/or shift for 0. When I run the code below (written in an embedded Python block),

```
"""
Embedded Python Blocks:

Each time this file is saved, GRC will instantiate the first class it finds
to get ports and parameters of your block. The arguments to __init__  will
be the parameters. All of them are required to have default values!
"""

import numpy as np
from gnuradio import gr


class SincFct(gr.sync_block):  # other base classes are basic_block, decim_block, interp_block
    """!
    Embedded Python Block - generating a sinc function
    """

    def __init__(self, samp_rate=32e3, amp=1.0, offset=0.0, shift=0.0, rect_span=1.0):  # only default arguments here
        """!
        Function generating a sinc function

        Input :
        -------
        samp_rate: <class float> (default: 32e3)
            Number of samples per second

        amp: <class float> (default: 1.0)
            Amplitude of the signal

        offset: <class float> (default: 0.0)
            Offset of the signal with respect to 0

        shift: <class float> (default: 0.0)
            Offset from t=0

        rect_span: <class float> (default: 1.0)
            Span of the windowing rectangle function
        """
        gr.sync_block.__init__(
            self,
            name='Sinc',   # will show up in GRC
            in_sig=[],
            out_sig=[np.float32]
        )
        self.samp_rate = samp_rate
        self.amp = amp
        self.offset = offset
        self.shift = shift
        self.rect_span = rect_span

        self.lim_p = self.rect_span + 0.5*self.shift + 1    # further end of rect()
        self.lim_n = self.lim_p - 2 * (self.rect_span + 1)  # closest end of rect()

    def rect(self, x):
        return np.where( abs(x)<=0.5, 1, 0 )

    def work(self, input_items, output_items):
        output_items[0][:] = self.amp * np.sinc([(i-self.shift) for i, v in enumerate(output_items[0])]) \
                                * self.rect((output_items[0]-0.5*self.shift)/self.rect_span) \
                                + self.offset

        return len(output_items[0][:])
```

I get the result displayed in the image,[image: here below] which does not look like a sinc() (the image was obtained by putting `samp_rate` to 32e3, `amp` to 1, `offset` and `shift` both to 0, and `rect_span` to 1.0).

Can anyone help me to figure out what is wrong?

Comment: could you describe what you want this to do? One thing that is definitely wrong: you assume the size of `output_items` is always the same; that's not the case. Every call to `work` will be different, and there will be infinitely many calls to `work` (or until you quit the program ;) )

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for your answer. The idea was just for me to play around with GNU Radio, and see if I could implement a signal source (a sinc in this particular case). If the size of `output_items` is variable, how should I implement my source to do what I want ? Have a nice day.
Alex

Comment: As I said, I don't understand what you mean with "what you want". Could you really write down what that is, explicitly? What's the value of the first sample you want to generate? What's the value of the $N$th?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I will try to be more explicit: I would like to generate a sinc() every `T` seconds, meaning at time `t=0` I have a sinc() with peak at `t=0`, then at time `t=T`, another sinc() with its peak located at `t=T`, etc. In résumé, at time `t=nT`, I would like to have sinc(t-nT). I hope this is less confusing, have a nice day, Alex.

Comment: ah cool, so there's a sum of shifted sincs, one shifted by 0, one shifted by $T$, one shifted by $2T$ and so on for eternity, and the value for every sample is the sum of all these, evaluated at that point? (that's not going to work, because we can't calculate infinite sums in finite time, PLUS this will converge to something you don't expect ;) but I hope I get more of what you want...)

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes you pinpointed exactly what I try to do ! :D
Have a nice day, Alex

Comment: so, now we have a problem: you want to calculate an infinite sum of sincs, because every single one of these has infinite extent in time.

Comment: @MarcusMüller This can be corrected by multiplying it by a square window (for example). So now a `sinc()` and a `rect()` function must be implemented, and then the results put together

Comment: ok, but then I'm again *guessing* what *you* want to do. Please **edit** your question to include a full spec of what you want to do!

Comment: Any thaught regarding the implementation of this sinc function, is it possible ? Thx !